# Proper name for the variant of Haldane estimator for handling empty cell in a 2xn contingency table

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, estimators, kruskal-wallis-test

I am using `R` and `survey` package to analyse a survey that several 2xn contingency tables need to be analysed using Chi square test and Kruskal-Wallis test (for ordered variable). Some of the contingency tables give empty cell, which gives p-value way smaller than 0.05 that I think the "significant" result is actually caused by the empty cell. These empty cells are non-structural zero, and I am thinking of ways to correct that.

I have come across the "[Haldane estimator](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=4WygAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-TW#v=onepage&q=haldane&f=false)" that 0.5 is added to each of the cell. This method is not applicable to me because I cannot apply the weight-adjusted chi square test or Kruskal-Wallis test by using directly the contingency table. I need to "inject" at least 1 into one of the data point of the dataset, so that the empty cell can be eliminated.

I found quite a few articles that instead of 0.5, but 1 is added into the empty cell:

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3738937/
- http://ascopubs.org/doi/full/10.1200/jco.2006.06.3560
- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1016.9751&rep=rep1&type=pdf
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3652452/

(You may want to search `was added to each` to find out the exact sentence that mention addition of 1 into empty cell)

These articles do not provide citation, or vaguely justify why one is added to each cells

If I need to proper justification, what should I call this maneuver of adding one into each cell in order to eliminate the empty cell? Should it be called the `Haldane estimator variant`? Or something else?

Thank you.